# Array not seen in namespace procedure but seen without namespace in procedure

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Morning all,

The below code shows a namespace with procedures and there is an array called ds_out.

If I run this code and press the enter button I get the error:

"Error: can't read "ds_out(0)!: no such variable

If I tick the checkbox and press enter it shows the message:

"KL15 is: 1" and if I untick the box it will read "KL15 is: 0"

If I comment out the namespace and just have the procedures it works fine.

Can anyone tell me why please?

```
namespace eval RELAY_SELECT {
tk::labelframe .rs -text "Relay Selection"
array set ds_out {
0   0
1   0 
}
proc create_RS_Labels {} {
tk::label .rs.kl15_lb -text "KL15" -justify center -width 5
}
proc create_RS_CBoxes {} {
tk::checkbutton .rs.kl15_cb -width 1 -height 1 -variable kl15_cb -command {if {$kl15_cb} {
set ds_out(0) 1
set ds_out(1) 1
} else {
set ds_out(0) 0
set ds_out(1) 0
} }
}
proc create_RS_enter_Button {} {
tk::button .rs.enter -borderwidth 1 -height 1 -text "Enter" -width 5 -command {if {$kl15_cb} {
set ds_out(0) 1
set ds_out(1) 1
puts "KL15 is: $ds_out(0)"
} else {
puts "KL15 is: $ds_out(0)"
set ds_out(0) 0
set ds_out(1) 0
}
}
}
proc create_RS_LabelFrame {} {

place .rs -x 10 -y 10
grid .rs.kl15_lb -row 0 -column 0 
grid .rs.kl15_cb -row 0 -column 1   
grid .rs.enter -row 12 -column 0 -columnspan 6
}
create_RS_Labels
create_RS_CBoxes
create_RS_enter_Button
create_RS_LabelFrame
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with variable scoping.

Tk command callbacks are always evaluated in the global scope. Your array is *not* in the global scope (and other variables like `kl15_cb` *are* global despite the fact that you might not expect them to be). This can get extremely confusing very quickly; you're strongly advised to make helper procedures for all callbacks. Here's your code reworked into how it should be for sanity's sake; pay particular attention to the `Note!` comments in there.

```
namespace eval RELAY_SELECT {
    # Note! Declare variables in namespaces, always, to avoid an obscure misfeature!
    variable kl15_cb 0
    variable ds_out
    array set ds_out {
        0   0
        1   0 
    }

    proc create_RS_Labels {frame} {
        tk::label $frame.kl15_lb -text "KL15" -justify center -width 5
    }

    proc create_RS_CBoxes {frame} {
        # Note! Fully qualified variable name!
        # Note! [namespace code] to make callback script!
        tk::checkbutton $frame.kl15_cb -width 1 -height 1 -variable ::RELAY_SELECT::kl15_cb \
                -command [namespace code { RS_CBox_callback }]
    }

    proc RS_CBox_callback {} {
        # Note! [variable] with *ONE* argument to bring var into procedure scope
        variable kl15_cb
        variable ds_out
        if {$kl15_cb} {
            set ds_out(0) 1
            set ds_out(1) 1
        } else {
            set ds_out(0) 0
            set ds_out(1) 0
        }
    }

    proc create_RS_enter_Button {frame} {
        tk::button $frame.enter -borderwidth 1 -height 1 -text "Enter" -width 5 \
                -command [namespace code { RS_enter_callback }]
    }

    proc RS_enter_callback {} {
        variable kl15_cb
        variable ds_out
        if {$kl15_cb} {
             set ds_out(0) 1
             set ds_out(1) 1
             puts "KL15 is: $ds_out(0)"
        } else {
             puts "KL15 is: $ds_out(0)"
             set ds_out(0) 0
             set ds_out(1) 0
        }
    }

    proc create_RS_LabelFrame {frame} {
        place $frame -x 10 -y 10
        grid $frame.kl15_lb -row 0 -column 0 
        grid $frame.kl15_cb -row 0 -column 1   
        grid $frame.enter -row 12 -column 0 -columnspan 6
    }

    tk::labelframe .rs -text "Relay Selection"
    create_RS_Labels .rs
    create_RS_CBoxes .rs
    create_RS_enter_Button .rs
    create_RS_LabelFrame .rs
}
```

For my own sanity, I've indented everything conventionally too.

Comment: Would you recommend using `-variable [namespace current]::kl15_cb` instead of hardcoding the namespace name in the proc?

Comment: Thanks guys I'll look into this.